# How to change Google Chrome UI Size on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04

How do I do that? I tried to follow the instructions for previous versions of Ubuntu but can't manage it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have *gnome-tweaks* installed, please install it using `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`. Then launch it by typing *tweaks* in the dash or *gnome-tweaks* in the window brought up with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

In there, click on *Fonts* in the pane on the left and choose the font size you want in your UI in the *Interface Text* section. (Keep in mind this will affect all applications, not just google-chrome.)

**gnome-tweaks GUI**

[image: Interface text]

This is what google-chrome looks like with *Ubuntu Regular 11*

**Ubuntu Regular 11**

[image]

And this is with a larger font size:

**Ubuntu Regular 16**

[image]

---

The limitation is that the font size in the address bar aka omnibar is unchanged. This is a long-standing [WontFix issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=276946).

Other SE links on the small size of fonts in the omnibar:

- [Text size in Chrome's omnibar is too small](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951126/text-size-in-chromes-omnibar-is-too-small)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343740/how-to-change-font-size-of-address-bar-in-chrome-programmatically